# Infinite Horizontal Scroll on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm not sure if any of you are familiar with Tumblr but I'm simply trying to attain a HORIZONTAL infinite scroll. Vertical infinite scrolls are easy to find.

Now, I did find one on jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle.net/URCwd/20](http://jsfiddle.net/URCwd/20)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to incorporate it into the Tumblr HTML.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You'd like posts to load seamlessly once the user gets closer to last one visible? The example you've linked is no good for you anyway - it's not infinite scrolling - what that script does is that it resets the scroll to start point once you reach the end.

Comment: In general you could just take most popular infinite scroll script (like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33625555/t.js) for tumblr and replace scrollTop property with scrollLeft it should work in, give or take, 5 minutes.

Comment: http://www.tumblr.com/theme/35230 This theme has infinite scroll horizontal, but it currently gets messed up, "loads posts under the main colum" vertically, when you change the post size above the default. Was trying to figure out how to fix it..

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollLeft() >= ($('body').width() - $(window).width()) ) {
            $('body').width('+=100');
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this on one of my themes by using Paul Irish's infinite scroll jquery plugin and essentially changing all the `height`s to `width`s and the `top`s to `left`s. Sounds rather fiddly but worked like a charm.

Comment: Charlotte, could you direct me to this file please?